# PHP looking for ext folder on wrong drive

Tags: php, composer-php

I have installed PHP 7 on windows 10 to my `E:` drive so I can try out composer.

When I try to run composer I get an error that it can't find the extensions I enabled but I can see it is looking in `C:\php\ext` and not `E:\php\ext`.

I looked in `php.ini` but  couldn't see whre to set the path of the root installation.

Does it always default to `C:`?  How do I tell it to look in `E:`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir

Comment: @MarcB Thanks that works.  Add it as an answer so I can close.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For some reason, PHP for Windows is hardwired to look for extensions in `C:\php\ext` no matter where you installed it. But there's a simple fix for this.

In your `php.ini`, look for the line `extension_dir =`. If it's disabled (as a comment), enable it.

You only need to mention the name of the folder where the extensions reside if this folder is inside your PHP installation folder. An absolute path is not necessary.

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Open a Command Prompt and run `php -a` to check if PHP complains about missing extensions. If not, you're doing good.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this bit of extra dumbness from PHP team... Every time I think I'm ready to defend PHP as a good tool, I find something else retarded they've done I have to pretend isn't a ridiculous obstacle.

Comment: If you got the missing library issue when you run PHP CLI in a different drive than the XAMPP installed drive, try changing the `\xampp\ ` with `E:\xampp\ `

Comment: Using `ext` does not work here, I need to give it the absolute path. Such a piece of crap it cannot even recognize its own directory... :S

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the answer above, using `extension_dir = ".\ext"` in the `php.ini` (Check `php --ini`) a relative path also works.